# Total variation of $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$, with $f(0):=0$. Calculate the total variation of $f$ on $[0,1]$.

It is simple to show that $f \in BV[0,1]$. However, since $f$ has infinitely many zeros on $[0,1]$, calculating $\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|dx$ is not straightforward. Is there a neat way to compute $V_{0}^{1}f$ or must one find the partition which achieves it and sum the series?

Comment: You alredy have the neat way for a differentiable function! $\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|dx$

Comment: Have you tried finding the local extrema of $f$? It should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing the derivative $f'(x)$ and using the change of variable $x=1/z$ yields the total variation $V$ of $f$ on $(0,1)$ as $$V=\int_1^\infty\mathrm e^{-z}\left|g(z)\right|\,\mathrm dz,\qquad g(z)=\sin(\pi z)-\pi\cos(\pi z).$$
Since $|g|$ has period $1$, $$V=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^{1}\mathrm e^{-z-n}\left|g(z)\right|\,\mathrm dz=\frac{W}{\mathrm e-1},\qquad W=\int_0^{1}\mathrm e^{-z}\left|g(z)\right|\,\mathrm dz.$$
Now, $g\lt0$ on $(0,z^*)$ and $g\gt0$ on $(z^*,1)$, where $\frac14\lt z^*\lt\frac12$ solves $$\tan(\pi z^*)=\pi,$$ hence one can express $W$ in terms of $z^*\approx.40191$. More precisely, $$\int\mathrm e^{-z}g(z)\,\mathrm dz=-\mathrm e^{-z}\,\sin(\pi z),$$ hence $$W=\left.\mathrm e^{-z}\sin(\pi z)\right|_0^{z^*}-\left.\mathrm e^{-z}\sin(\pi z)\right|_{z^*}^1=2\mathrm e^{-z^*}\sin(\pi z^*)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1+\pi^2}}\mathrm e^{-z^*}.$$